# having regex object is it possible to recreate the string pattern back from it?

Tags: c++, regex, gcc

So I create a simple regex object:

```
std::regex regex_obj("find +me");
```

but then:

```
regex_obj.str()
```

or

```
regex_obj.c_str()
```

returns error: `error: 'std::regex' has no member named 'str'`

Bare cout also does not understand how to convert regex object to string, but with boost  it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp> 

int main() {
  boost::regex boost_regex_object("^find +me");
  std::cout << boost_regex_object.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [There is no `str()` member.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)

Comment: @chris: I know, but there maybe is another function that could extract the pattern it does not have to be named in that convention.

Comment: The reference suggests no such function.